# Linux kernel address relocation

Tags: linux, memory-address, relocation, virtual-address-space

I don't understand a thing about the address relocation process of Linux at boot time. This process affects only virtual addresses or also the physical ones? I tried to figure it out by myself reading the Linux source code, but I'm still having the doubt.

Also, if only virtual addresses are relocated this means that the kernel is physically in the first GB of memory and the user code in the rest of memory, but if I'm right the interrupt vector is moved to the high memory too (at least in the ARM case). So there isn't the risk that the page frame allocator gives to a process a page containing these addresses, making blowing up all?

Comment: Not a specific answer to your question, but there's this little great piece of work in progress: A book that tackles the insides of the Linux kernel and explains the why and how. https://0xax.gitbooks.io/linux-insides/content/index.html

Comment: That's awesome! Thank you! Do you know if there's something like that but for ARM processor?